# how to send image address and id

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to send id with page address and send image address but my code is wrong

i use codeigniter

```php
 <?php 
    $i=0;
    foreach($select as $row){  

    echo '<tr align="center"><a href="'.echo base_url().'"index.php/news/news_show_view?id="'.$row['id'].'">
      <td>'.$i.'</td>
      <td>'.$row['news_title'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['news_text'].'</td>
      <td ><img src="'.echo base_url().'"images/'.$row['news_Img'].'"></td>
    </tr></a>';
    }
  echo '</tbody>
</table>';


?>
```

i want send id and show image

Comment: I have error with my addresses

Comment: dear @zahra , just replace all `echo base_url()` with `base_url()` , echo is not allowed inside another one

Comment: you should get familiar with this syntax as well: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/alternative_php.html#alternative-control-structures

Comment: tnx i can connect to db but i have problem with id and img still

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
<a href="' . base_url() . 'url/url_path' . $your->id . '">
```